# Hadoop port 50070 in use Windows installation error

Tags: hadoop, port, namenode

I am a newbie in hadoop and trying to create a standalone hadoop cluster in windows. I am getting an error while starting the name node as shown below. However, upon checking in windows for the process using the port 50070 i could not find any process

**Hadoop Error:**

```
20/04/18 08:32:24 ERROR namenode.NameNode: Failed to start namenode.
java.net.BindException: Port in use: 0.0.0.0:50070
        at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2.openListeners(HttpServer2.java:919)
        at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2.start(HttpServer2.java:856)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeHttpServer.start(NameNodeHttpServer.java:142)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.startHttpServer(NameNode.java:752)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:638)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:811)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:795)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1488)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1554)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChannelConnector.java:216)
        at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2.openListeners(HttpServer2.java:914)
        ... 8 more
20/04/18 08:32:24 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
20/04/18 08:32:24 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
```

**Windows Port check:**

```
λ netstat -ano | findstr :50070
```

C:\work\hadoop-2.7.2\sbin

Could someone please help fixing this issue?

Comment: Why aren't you using the latest stable version of Hadoop? Why not use Cloudera Quickstart VM?

Answer (score 2):

Good Morning!
Do the following, before uploading the docker, open the windows console and search for its working ports with the command:
`net stat -a -n -o`

- **-a:** *displays all TCP and UDP connections and ports.*
- **-n:** *display port numbers instead of name.*
- **-o:** *displays the PID.*

That way, all you have to do is kill the service and go up again:

```
Taskkill / PID <pid> / F
```